# Метки "moderators" и "election" на Мете

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

У нас вторые выборы - и второй раз в сообщении от духа сообщества вручную редактируются метки. :-)

Похоже, что эти метки - "системные", т.е. используются на всех сайтах сети. Насколько я знаю, такие метки принято не удалять, а делать синонимами к русскоязычным.

Поэтому, я считаю, метка [election](/questions/tagged/election) обязана стать синонимом к [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b)

Непонятно что делать с меткой [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) - русскоязычного аналога у нас нет.

Comment: Не факт, что это поможет. Так как при переносе с основного сайта всё равно приходится вручную править [meta-tag:discussion]. Писал об этом на [mse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/339911).